# JavaFX. Как в Chart установить ширину значений

Tags: java, javafx, диаграммы

**Вопрос:** Как в Chart установить ширину значений по оси X. В примере они отображаются оранжевым цветом.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Код:**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestChart extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        //System.out.println(xAxis.getCategorySpacing());
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final BarChart<String, Number> chart = new BarChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);

        XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("V", 1));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("O", 2));

        chart.getData().addAll(series1);

        Scene scene = new Scene(chart, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

public class TestChart extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        //System.out.println(xAxis.getCategorySpacing());
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final BarChart<String, Number> chart = new BarChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);

        XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("V", 1));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("O", 2));

        chart.getData().addAll(series1);

        Scene scene = new Scene(chart, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, там должен быть метод `.setBarGap(3);` который изменяет расстояние между "столбиками".

А толщина самих столбцов растягивается динамически.

Вот [инструкция](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/bar-chart.htm).

Comment: BarGap определяет разрыв между барами. А нужно уменьшить ширину баров. Разрыв не уменьшит общую ширину диграммы по оси Х. Это я сделаю отдельным вопросом с другим примером кода. Т. к. объяснить кратко не получается.

Comment: Так в том то и дело, что бары заполняют свободное пространство динамически. Чем больше место - тем больше бары. Чем больше баров - тем они меньше. Раз баров больше не будет, нужно расширить интервалы между ними. Тогда они сами станут уже. (Решил поискать альтернативу на английском SO - там сделали также)